# Issue inserting ampersands into MySQL

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, pdo

I've been trying to fix this issue for a while, I've spent endless amounts of time on the web searching for a solution for it. So I thought I'd come to you guys since I am at wits end with this problem. Basically I have a CMS system that I designed a while back, I recently updated it to modern standards using PDO and such like, now I seem to have an issue inserting ampersands (&) into the MySQL database, everything is set to 'UTF-8', the PDO connection, the MySQL collation, everything, yet for some reason when there is an ampersand in the form from the textarea's, the data is sent, but is cut off when it reaches the ampersand, as if it's parsing it and cutting it off because it thinks that the ampersand is a vulnerability.

Here is my code for the insert in PHP:

```
            $fbl = $_POST['fblValue'];
        $fbr = $_POST['fbrValue'];
        $sbl = $_POST['sblValue'];
        $sbr = $_POST['sbrValue'];
        $tbl = $_POST['tblValue'];
        $tbr = $_POST['tbrValue'];
        $fblDisabled = $_POST['fblDisabled'];
        $fbrDisabled = $_POST['fbrDisabled'];
        $sblDisabled = $_POST['sblDisabled'];
        $sbrDisabled = $_POST['sbrDisabled'];
        $tblDisabled = $_POST['tblDisabled'];
        $tbrDisabled = $_POST['tbrDisabled'];
        $footer = $_POST['footerValue'];
        $copyright = $_POST['copyrightValue'];

        $statement = $conn->prepare("UPDATE pages SET FBL = :fbl, 
                                                    FBLDisabled = :fblDisabled, 
                                                    FBR = :fbr, 
                                                    FBRDisabled = :fbrDisabled, 
                                                    SBL = :sbl, SBLDisabled = :sblDisabled, 
                                                    SBR = :sbr, SBRDisabled = :sbrDisabled, 
                                                    TBL = :tbr, TBLDisabled = :tblDisabled, 
                                                    TBR = :tbr, TBRDisabled = :tbrDisabled, 
                                                    Footer = :footer, 
                                                    Copyright = :copyright 
                                                    WHERE ID = :pageToEdit");
        $statement->bindParam(":fbl", $fbl);
        $statement->bindParam(":fblDisabled", $fblDisabled);
        $statement->bindParam(":fbr", $fbr);
        $statement->bindParam(":fbrDisabled", $fbrDisabled);
        $statement->bindParam(":sbl", $sbl);
        $statement->bindParam(":sblDisabled", $sblDisabled);
        $statement->bindParam(":sbr", $sbr);
        $statement->bindParam(":sbrDisabled", $sbrDisabled);
        $statement->bindParam(":tbl", $tbl);
        $statement->bindParam(":tblDisabled", $tbDisabled);
        $statement->bindParam(":tbr", $tbr);
        $statement->bindParam(":tbrDisabled", $tbrDisabled);
        $statement->bindParam(":footer", $footer);
        $statement->bindParam(":copyright", $copyright);
        $statement->bindParam(":pageToEdit", $pageToEdit);
        $statement->execute();              
    }
```

Also may I add, that I use ajax to send the data, is there a possibility that it's something to do with that?

Here is the AJAX code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">


        function savePage(str1, str2, str3, str4, str5, str6, str7, str8, str9, str10, str11, str12, str13, str14)
        {
            var xmlhttp;

            if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
            {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            else
            {// code for IE6, IE5
                xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }

            xmlhttp.open("post", "putEditedPage.php", true);
            xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            xmlhttp.send("fblValue=" + str1 + "&fbrValue=" + str2 + "&sblValue=" + str3 + "&sbrValue=" + str4 + "&tblValue=" + str5 + "&tbrValue=" + str6 + "&fblDisabled=" + str7 + "&fbrDisabled=" + str8 + "&sblDisabled=" + str9 + "&sbrDisabled=" + str10 + "&tblDisabled=" + str11 + "&tbrDisabled=" + str12 + "&footerValue=" + str13 + "&copyrightValue=" + str14);
            document.getElementById('blackout').style.display="block";
            document.getElementById('Alert').style.display="block";
            document.getElementById('Alert').style.marginTop=((window.innerHeight/2)+((window.innerHeight/100) * 35))+"px";
            setTimeout(function(){
                document.getElementById('blackout').style.display='none';           
                document.getElementById('Alert').style.display='none';
            }, 1250);
        }
        function insertTab(o, e)
        {
            var kC = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.charCode ? e.charCode : e.which;
            if (kC == 9 && !e.shiftKey && !e.ctrlKey && !e.altKey)
            {
                var oS = o.scrollTop;
                if (o.setSelectionRange)
                {
                    var sS = o.selectionStart;
                    var sE = o.selectionEnd;
                    o.value = o.value.substring(0, sS) + "\t" + o.value.substr(sE);
                    o.setSelectionRange(sS + 1, sS + 1);
                    o.focus();
                }
                else if (o.createTextRange)
                {
                    document.selection.createRange().text = "\t";
                    e.returnValue = false;
                }
                o.scrollTop = oS;
                if (e.preventDefault)
                {
                    e.preventDefault();
                }
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

    </script>
```

Thanks in advance guys, cheers.

Comment: Just rectified that problem, sorry guys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right here:

```
xmlhttp.send("fblValue=" + str1 + "&fbrValue=" + str2 + "&sblValue=" + str3 + ...
                                   ^                     ^
```

See those ampersands? They are special characters in URL encoding. To submit a value which contains ampersands itself, you need to escape that ampersand using URL encoding. Therefore, [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) your values before concatenating them into a URL-encoded string.

Maybe I can interest you in: [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism/)

Comment: It didn't work, I moved the send string into a new variable and used the 'encodeURIComponent' function, but it's still doing the same thing unfortunately.

Comment: Debug more. Look at your browser network inspection tools what exactly is sent to the server. Log the values you receive on the server somewhere so you can check them (`var_dump($_POST)` or equivalent). Check each step. There are many things that can go wrong along the chain Form → AJAX → PHP → PDO → database. Figure out where exactly it fails.

Comment: How do I output the var_dump() data when the data is sent via post? Does var_dump, dump into some sort of file?

Comment: If you `var_dump`, you'll see it in the browser's developer tools as response to the AJAX request. Otherwise, use `var_export` to write it somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Special characters are supported in PDO, Ajax, XML.

You must have little hole here: "*everything is set to 'UTF-8'*".

Check these things:

1. HTML page charset (here: `<head></head>`)
2. Encoding of JS file?

   `<script src="file.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">`
3. XML (i have no idea where)
4. Database connection (set names, collation)
5. Collation set on specyfic column
6. Charset of source files
7. If you are using some editor in JavaScript - maybe it has charset in config file?

You may try "step by step" debug. You may try to insert ampersand without AJAX.

Answer (score -2):

Don't forget your ability to use http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php

Comment: Because the "html code" for an ampersand is `&amp;`, which contains an ampersand...?

Comment: lol You beat me there deceze, I surrender to illogical thought.